# fire texture look worst in render then view

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor

Why in the viewport the fire texture looks nice but you can't get the same result in the shading on render mode?

Why not put the texture of the viewport on the render view?

Comment: Hello and welcome, Elad :). Please add some images to better illustrate your issue. Like *viewport result* vs. *render result.*